# How do I convert outlook "to-do" items to "tasks"

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I often use the left click to flag an important item that I can't answer at the moment but need to come check again after I finish my email and decide its priority.

I have noticed that as I finish these items. There is no history of it. I have discovered I can only view completed items for "tasks". "to-do" items disappear upon completion.

Is there a way to have the default behavior for red flagging an item be to add it to "tasks"? If not, how do I convert a "to-do" to a "task"?

Answer (score 0):

Flagged emails in the Task view are only visible when you select the 'To-Do List' in the tree on the left side (as seen at help.med.unc.edu/training/microsoft/outlook2010/tasks/overview ).

If your completed flagged emails do not show up in the 'To-Do List' you may have to customize your view to [show all tasks that are marked complete](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/outlook-help/show-all-tasks-that-are-marked-complete-HA010355602.aspx).

To convert a email to a real task there are three quick ways to [create a task from an Outlook item](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/outlook-help/create-tasks-and-to-do-items-HA010354415.aspx#_Toc260826382).

Answer (score 0):

2023 Answer:

About 6 years later from your question, Microsoft has addressed this by introducing [*Microsoft To Do*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_To_Do) app, available on all major platforms. You can run it in parallel to your Microsoft Office and it is intended to replace old Tasks screen in most cases. This app automatically includes all your flagged e-mails in To Do list in a way you expected. You can disable/enable this feature on *Settings* screen.

The only potential downside of the app is that under the hood, all objects are old objects (tasks, e-mails) and to manipulate them programmatically, you need to use the old ways. Some of new features of the Microsoft To Do app are not programmatically accessible at all, for example order of tasks displayed in the app, especially if arranged manually by drag&drop.

A link to Windows Store:
https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/microsoft-to-do-lists-tasks-reminders/9NBLGGH5R558

Answer (score -1):

you can do this via quick steps. new quickstep - custom - under categories tasks and flags, choose either "create a task with attachment" (my preferred approach as it keeps the attachments in email) or "create task with text of message".